# How to cancel font shadow in nuke pyside

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside, nuke

I have a UI, which automatically sets font shadow in nuke, and how to cancel it.
[image]

I want the font on this button to look like this, so there is no font shadow.
[image]

This is my code,Thanks:)

```
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-

from PySide import QtGui


class MyButton(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super(MyButton, self).__init__(parent)

        v_layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)

        btn = QtGui.QPushButton("Submit")
        v_layout.addWidget(btn)

        self.setStyleSheet("""
        QPushButton{
            height: 50px;
            border: 0px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
            font-size: 18px;
            font-family: "Microsoft YaHei";
            border-radius: 4px;
            color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 255);
            background-color: #7cd1ef;
        }

        """)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app=QtGui.QApplication([])

    mb = MyButton()
    mb.show()

    app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the default style that Nuke uses. To change it, you'll need to set a different style... like so:

```
self.setStyle(QtGui.QStyleFactory.create('Plastique'))
```