# How to remove drop shadows from presumably inhereted QLabel style in PySide?

Tags: python, css, pyside, nuke

I'm executing a python program within a program (Nuke) which embeds its Python interpreter and its own version of PySide.

My program has it's own CSS stylesheet, which is counteracting the default stylesheet from the "parent" program. I could overwrite every inherited style by specifying a new value for each changed properties, except from one: It seems that my QLabel widgets have some drop shadow that I can't get rid of. I tried adding the following CSS code in my stylesheet, but it doesn't change anything:

```
QLabel {text-shadow: none}
```

or

```
QLabel {shadow: none}
```

It still looks like this:

[image: 1]

And I don't want that drop shadow. Which CSS property could it be?

Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/14016704/8150685.  That is an example of creating a shadow for a `QLabel`.  If you create and assign an empty shadow to the `QLabel` you may be able to get rid of your current shadow.  If that works let me know and I can make a cleaner answer for someone who has this issue in the future.

Comment: Good shout! Unfortunately it doesn't remove the existing shadow nor even shows a shadow.

Comment: Welp sorry mate. Was worth a shot. It could be your css is overriding the python for some reason or that what you are seeing isn't a shadow but a border or background. Is the QLabel within a QWidget?

Comment: Good point about the shadow being a border or bg, I'll check that now. And yes, all the QLabels are within a QWidget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution on Stack Overflow: [How to cancel font shadow in nuke pyside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52838690/how-to-cancel-font-shadow-in-nuke-pyside)

The problem was due to the default style used by Nuke.

As suggested in the answer from the link, specifying another one fixed the issue:

`self.setStyle(QtGui.QStyleFactory.create('Plastique'))`